# Compare epoch date from string against xAxis dates in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, highcharts, epoch

I've been trying to compare a date that's in the function checkDatabase against the dates in the xaxis. I converted them with Date() and tried to compare just the getDate() from the date objects created from the epoch.

Basically I need to compare dates coming from a database against the dates in the xaxis and if there's a match run through the if condition. Would appreciate any help with this

Thanks

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/pTXws/50/)

```
   $(function () {
       var chart;
       chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
               renderTo: 'container'
           },
           global: {
               useUTC: false
           },
           xAxis: {
               type: 'datetime',
               labels: {
                   useHTML: true,
                   formatter: function () {
                       var d = new Date(parseInt(this.value));
                       return d.getDate();
                       //return this.value;
                       if (checkDatabase(this.value)) {
                           return 'test';
                       } else {
                           return 'else';
                       }
                   }
               }
           },

           series: [{
               data: [
                   [1147651200000, 40],
                   [1147737600000, 25]
               ]
           }]
       });
   });

   function checkDatabase(nd) {
       //return val = '1147651200000';
       var nd = new Date(parseInt(1147651200000));
       return nd.getDate();
   }
```

Comment: Basically it's not clear for me what you want to achieve, sorry. You have function `checkDatabase()` which should check something - and then according to that checking you want display format A ('test') or format B ('else'), right?

Comment: @PawełFus I'll be querying a database to get back an array of dates, in the example is just trying to use a single date. If any of these dates in the array match a date in the series data then the condition is true and a custom label is added to the axis.

Comment: But it will take a while to communicate with server, while Highcharts just want to draw simple label.. I think you should use xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes event - there you can get displayed timespan (from date - to date), so you could filter on backend what exactly is displayed. What do you think?

Comment: @PawełFus i'm not clear on what you're saying. What if I product the array sever side with php, then for each of the dates do an render.image but I don't know how to set the X position dynamically based on a date position in the xaxis?

Comment: Maybe we should start from the beginning - what exactly you want to achieve? Do you have simple mockup for this? If you want to add some images on a chart for specific date - can't you just use scatter series with marker as image? Btw, to translate from timestamp to pixel position use `chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(timestamp);`

Comment: @PawełFus in my example above, you see my data has a date 1147651200000 so when a function runs and finds 1147651200000 in my database I want a graphic with link put on the xaxis right where 1147651200000 is labeled. So any dates from the database which match a date on the xaxis put a graphic/link

Comment: Okay, how about that solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/461/ ? You will always show that dates inside the chart with url/image.

Comment: @PawełFus thanks that's great, do you know if it would work with epoch dates?

Comment: @PawełFus I think I got it http://jsfiddle.net/peter/3bQne/463/ I see how use set the tick positions and this seems to work with a epoch as a position

Comment: `Date.UTC()`  create timestamp in milliseconds since 1970 - and this is required format for Highcharts datetime axis.

Comment: @PawełFus Look at this example using two dates in tick positions, why is one a bit higher / lower than the other ? http://jsfiddle.net/peter/frS3V/ they seem to stagger the more that are added.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you talking about.. both are on the same position. Try to set strict charts width to recreate issue. However - use staggerLines to prevent this.